# What is wrong in following query?

Tags: stored-procedures, if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to fetch data from database based on some string i.e nvarchar parameters using store procedure.

I am trying following query:

```
IF (@Ticket_Status IS NOT NULL AND @Ticket_Status = 'Open')
    Begin
         Select * From Tickets
         Where Ticket_Status = 'Open'
    End
else
    Begin
         Select * From Tickets
         Where Ticket_Status = 'Closed'
    End
```

but it gives me no result.

If I try simple query like:

```
Select * From Tickets
Where Ticket_Status = 'Open'
```

it gives me appropriate result. What I am doing wrong?Is this the right way to use If Else in SQL Store Procedure?

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. What is the data type of the column? What is the data type of the parameter? How exactly are you calling it? Does "no results" mean no query is returned, or a query is returned but it is empty? Did you try adding `PRINT` statements inside each `IF` to see which branch is being reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need two copies of the query and a big `IF` conditional. Also there is no reason to check if it is `NOT NULL` *and* equal to something. If the latter is true, the former also has to be true.

```
Select <cols> 
From dbo.Tickets
Where Ticket_Status = COALESCE(@Ticket_Status, N'Closed');
```

Comment: ok I understand that I don't need to check NOT NULL but still what's wrong with if condition.

Comment: actually I need to write more complex query using If condition that's why I am trying with simple query's first to better understand it.